# How to see the content of a commit when rewording its message using 'git rebase'?

Tags: git, git-rebase, commit-message, git-interactive-rebase

I'm fixing some commit messages of a series of commits. I start

```
git rebase --interactive
```

mark some commits for rewording and then edit the messages. It'd be really helpful if I could see the diff of each commit in the editor, just like when doing `git commit -v`. Is something like this possible with `rebase`?

(I could also just `edit` the commits and then see the diffs, but this is much slower and less convenient.)

Answer (score 1):

You could write a `prepare-commit-msg` hook to add more information to the suggested message before the editor starts.  You can tell that you're in a rebase by looking at certain state files that get created in `.git`.  You could regenerate the diffs, but the patches for all of the commits unwound by `rebase` are in a subdirectory of `.git`.